# class problems csv php

Tags: php, csv, class

I can't understand the csv class, I made this one below but it doesn't work I need an example for me to understand how to make this class

```html
class Csv 
{ 
    public $extension;
    public $Reader;
    
    function Extension($Csv) 
    {
        $this->Reader = $Csv; 
    }
    function Reader($extension) 
    {
        $this->Extension = $extension;
    }
```

```html
 $Csv = new Csv('file');
 $Csv -> extension;
 $Csv -> Reader;
```

Comment: Do you not see that the `Extension($Csv)` 1. has a parameter that has to be passed on its call and 2. Is spelt with a UPPER CASE `E`

Comment: Also the class is missing a terminating `}`

Comment: The class does not have a `__contruct()` method so passing a parameter on `$Csv = new Csv('file');` wont work as there is nothing to process it

Comment: There is also no code to look at what you have done, so how do you know there is a probelms with what has done. Add a `print_r($Csv);` and you will at least see something

Comment: Method Reader set the Extension property? Stop, take a breath, think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Csv 
{ 
    public $Extension;
    public $Reader;
    
    function Extension($param) 
    {
        $this->Extension = $param; 
    }
    function Reader($param) 
    {
        $this->Reader = $param;
    }
}

$Csv = new Csv();
$Csv -> Extension('file');
$Csv -> Reader('docket');

print_r($Csv);
```

RESULT

```
Csv Object
(
    [Extension] => docket
    [Reader] => file
)
```

Comment: to understand and it worked